# In CSS, how to set height and width at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I saw there is `padding` and `margin` shortcut. When only one parameter is provided for `padding` or `margin`, other parameters will be set automatically.

For example,

`padding: 1px` will set `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `padding-left` and `padding-right` all to `1px`.

Sometimes I want to create a square whose `height` and `width` are the same, I was wonder there is a shortcut to set `height` and `width` in one line.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no such thing.

Comment: short answer is NO you can't

Comment: CSS doesn't have that. However, you can use a CSS framework (such as LESS) to create such behavior (using Parametric Mixins).

Comment: No its not possible. In case, you set background then you can use "background-size" in css that has width and height in one line.